# Determinant of a block upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

How prove the following equality for a block matrix?

$$\det\left[\begin{array}[cc]\\A&C\\
0&B\end{array}\right]=\det(A)\det(B)$$

I tried to use a proof by induction but I'm stuck. Is there a simpler method? Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determinant of a block lower triangular matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix) and [The determinant of block triangular matrix as product of determinants of diagonal blocks](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266068/the-determinant-of-block-triangular-matrix-as-product-of-determinants-of-diagona).

Comment: There is a deeper truth to this than just the proof itself.  While a matrix doesn't have the commutative multiplication of a field, most linear algebra results can be rephrased to not assume multiplicative commutivity.  Therefore any matrix can be though of as a 2x2 matrix of matrices, and most results follow inductively from the 2x2 case.

Answer (score 17):

Other answers suggest quite elementary proofs, and I upvoted one of them. However, I want to propose a technically easier, but less elementary proof.

If you're familiar with it, you can use [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). Let

$$A = Q_A R_A, \quad B = Q_B R_B$$

be QR decompositions of $A$ and $B$. Then

\begin{align*}
\det \begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} &= \det \begin{bmatrix} Q_A R_A & Q_A Q_A^T C \\ 0 & Q_B R_B \end{bmatrix} = \det \left( \begin{bmatrix} Q_A \\ & Q_B \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R_A & Q_A^T C \\ 0 & R_B \end{bmatrix} \right) \\
&= \det \begin{bmatrix} Q_A \\ & Q_B \end{bmatrix} \det \begin{bmatrix} R_A & Q_A^T C \\ 0 & R_B \end{bmatrix} = \det Q \det R,
\end{align*}

where

$$Q := \begin{bmatrix} Q_A \\ & Q_B \end{bmatrix}, \quad R := \begin{bmatrix} R_A & Q_A^T C \\ 0 & R_B \end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice that $R$ is (upper) triangular, so its determinant is equal to the product of its diagonal elements, so

$$\det R = \det \begin{bmatrix} R_A & 0 \\ 0 & R_B \end{bmatrix}.$$

Combining what we have,

\begin{align*}
\det \begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} &= \det Q \det R = \det \begin{bmatrix} Q_A \\ & Q_B \end{bmatrix} \det \begin{bmatrix} R_A \\ & R_B \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \det Q_A \det Q_B \det A \det B = \det (Q_AR_A) \det (Q_B R_B) \\
&= \det A \det B.
\end{align*}

Notice that this is far from elementary proof. It uses the QR decomposition, a formula for the determinant of block diagonal matrices, a formula for the determinant of triangular matrices, and block multiplication of matrices.

Comment: I personally don't like too much a proof that works in a much more restricted setting (real matrices) than the result that is being proved requires (here that is matrices over a commutative ring), even it one should be primarily interested in that restricted setting. That is because uch a proof suggests a relation that just isn't there.

Comment: Gaussian elimination definitely does not work for matrices over arbitrary commutative rings.

Comment: But the QR-decompostion is just a special case of the Iwasawa decomposition, so it works at least in somewhat more generality than is suggested...

Comment: If you prove it for real-valued matrices, you've proved it for matrices with values in an arbitrary commutative unital ring. 

LHS minus RHS of the desired identity is an integer-coefficient polynomial $F$ in the entries of $A,B,C$. 
We've proved that $F$ evaluates to 0 at any point of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Thus, $F$ is 0 as an element of  $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots, x_N]$. So it evaluates to 0 any point of $R^N$ for any commutative unital ring $R$.

Answer (score 16):

Since I have criticised some other answers, let me be fair and give my take on this. The result to use is just the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) defining the determinant (for once, use the definition!):
$$
\def\sg{\operatorname{sgn}}
\det(M) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sg(\sigma) \prod_{i = 1}^n M_{i,\sigma(i)}.
$$
Now if $M$ is the matrix of the question, and its block $A$ has size $k\times k$, then by the block form $M_{i,j}=0$ whenever $j\leq k<i$ (lower left hand block). So we can drop all permutations from the sum for which $\sigma(i)\leq k$ for any $i\in\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$. But that means that for $\sigma$ to survive, the $n-k$ values $\sigma(i)$ for are $i\in T=\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$ must all be in the $n-k$-element set $T$, and they must of course also be distinct: they form a permutation of the elements of$~T$. So $\sigma$ permutes them elements of $T$ among each other, and then necessarily also the elements of the complement $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ of$~T$. These permutations of subsets are independent, so the surviving permutations are naturally in bijection with the Cartesian product of the permutations of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and those of$~T$. Also the sign of the combination of two such permutations is the product of the signs of the individual permutations. All in all one gets
$$
\begin{align}
  \det(M)&=\sum_{\pi \in S_k} \sum_{\tau\in S_T} \sg(\pi)\sg(\tau) \left(\prod_{i = 1}^k M_{i,\pi(i)}\right)\prod_{i \in T}M_{i,\tau(i)}
\\&=\left(\sum_{\pi \in S_k}\sg(\pi)\prod_{i = 1}^k M_{i,\pi(i)}\right)\left(\sum_{\tau\in S_T}\sg(\tau)\prod_{i \in T}M_{i,\tau(i)}\right)
\\&=\det (A)\det(B).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How would this work if the matrix of zero's was in the lower right?

Comment: @user342914 For a matrix of the form $(\begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\C&0\end{smallmatrix})$ _with $B$ and $C$ square_ has a determinant which is $\pm\det(B)\det(C)$ where the sign is that of the permutation of columns that transforms the matrix to the form $(\begin{smallmatrix}B&A\\0&C\end{smallmatrix})$ (it is $-1$ if and only if both $B$ and $C$ have an odd size). It might be more natural to have $A$ and $0$ square, but in that case there is no obvious formula.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Use [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) to get what you need.

Comment: I don't see how I can use the Laplace expansion and why the matrix $C$ hasn't an effect on the result.

Comment: Select last $k$ rows of the matrix, where $k$ is the number of the rows of the $0$-part. What minors  of $k$-th order are not equal to 0? What are their algebraic complements?

Comment: The link you provided only does Laplace expansion for one row at the time. So at least you might want to state what Laplace expansion of $k$ rows at the time is exactly.