# How is the matrix identity $\det\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&A\end{pmatrix}=\det(A+B)\det(A-B)$ proved?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

The [Wikipedia page about the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) mentions the following matrix identity
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&A\end{pmatrix}=\det(A+B)\det(A-B),$$
valid for squared matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size.

How is this result proved?

Comment: The proof is given at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) page. It follows from the Leibniz formula, for example. Several proofs are given. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522385/determinant-of-a-block-matrix), which is the main step.

Comment: *A* and $B$ can't be really arbitrary: they have to be  square matrices of the same size.

Comment: @DietrichBurde mmh I'm sorry where is it given? I can't see it on the wiki page

Comment: @DietrichBurde [I saw that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3322302/173147), but it's not obvious to me how to use that identity. I also saw that remark in the wiki, but I don't find that clear at all

Comment: Go to this text in the wiki page:"When the blocks are square matrices of the same order further formulas hold. For example, if C and D commute (i.e., CD = DC), then the following formula comparable to the determinant of a 2 × 2 matrix holds:[13]". Then look up the reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I&I \\
0&I \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A&B \\
B&A \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I& -I \\
0 &I \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A+B& 0 \\
B& A-B \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: great, thanks! Is there also a similar formula for the case with the upper-right $B$ being instead $-B$, that you know of?