# $\det\left[ \begin{matrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{matrix} \right] \ = \ \det\left( A + B \right) \det( A - B )$ for $AB \neq BA$

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

For two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, we have the identity
$$
\det\left[ \begin{matrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{matrix} \right] \ = \ \det\left( A + B \right) \det( A - B ) \ .
$$
This is supposed to hold even when the matrices are non-commuting *ie.* $A B \neq BA$.

In the case that $AB=BA$, I can see how the above follows from the identity $$
\det\left[ \begin{matrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{matrix} \right] \ = \ \det(D) \det\left( A - B D^{-1} C \right)
$$
by taking $(C,D) \to (B,A)$ and mutiplying the argument of the determinants together, leads to
$$
\det\left[ \begin{matrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{matrix} \right] \ \to \ \det(A) \det\left( A - B A^{-1} B \right) = \det\left( A^2 - B A^{-1} B A \right) = \det\left( A^2 - B^2 \right) =  \det\left( A - B \right)\det\left( A + B \right)
$$
but the above proof relies heavily on $AB=BA$.

How do you see this identity is true in the case that $AB\neq BA$?

Comment: Try with $$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I&I \\
0&I \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A&B \\
B&A \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I& -I \\
0 &I \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A+B& 0 \\
B& A-B \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$ 
As in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322357/proof-of-the-matrix-identity-det-beginpmatrixab-ba-endpmatrix-detab?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By elementary operations over the columns and the rows of the matrix, you have$$\det\left[ \begin{matrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{matrix} \right] \ = \det\left[ \begin{matrix} A+B & B \\ B+A & A \end{matrix} \right] \ = \det\left[ \begin{matrix} A+B & B \\ 0 & A-B \end{matrix} \right] $$

which gives the formula.